# Conflicting instructions on refill tube with Fluidmaster universal repair kit

Tags: toilet

In the part that describes installation of the refill tube (via refill clip), the instructions say: "Warning: Placing the refill tube down the overflow pipe can cause significant waste of water".

But then on the other hand, in the troubleshooting section for the problem of "Water level in bowl is too low" it says "Make sure the refill tube supplies water to the overflow pipe".

What gives? How can those both be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that if the refill tube is placed fully down the overflow pipe it is possible to setup a siphon, pulling the water valve open and using large amounts of water.
The correct installation is to use the clip so the refill tube is aimed at and enters the overflow pipe. There should be a visible air gap between the bottom of the refill tube's nozzle and the top of the overflow pipe. See the attached image:[image: Fluidmaster Air Gap, Refill tube installation]

Comment: All right, that's exactly what I needed for some added confidence. And funny enough, the image you picked is the exact set that I got.

Answer (score 0):

That is two different things.
For the first “Putting the supply tube directly into the overflow” will send the water directly to waste

For the second, adjusting the height of the overflow so that it coincides plus a bit with the level set by the inlet and valve is to make sure it is just above the water level. If it is too low then the inlet never gets turned off as the water never reaches the correct level .